# Routing issue after changing primary keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

After changing primary key from `ID` to `PostId`, it seems that the `Post` `Details.cshtml` view does not render the URL correctly.

If I navigate to `https://localhost:xxxxx/Posts/Details/4`, the page renders correctly. However, the `@Html.ActionLink` call in the `Index.cshtml` view that was working previously now no longer works. It points to `https://localhost:xxxxx/Posts/Details?PostId=4`, which is a blank page. It seems like that URL should work, though, so I'm not sure whether the routing is the issue or it's something to do with the view. The same issue is occurring with a separate class (which also had its primary key changed).

The `<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.PostId">Details</a>` link in the `Index.cshtml` view *does* work by pointing to `https://localhost:xxxxx/Posts/Details/4`.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Post>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["TitleSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["AuthorSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author.LastName)</a>
            </th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", "Posts", new { item.PostId })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.Author.FullName, "Details", "Authors", new { item.Author.AuthorId })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PostId">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.PostId">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.PostId">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**PostsController.cs** (relevant `Details` get method only)

```
namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Website.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PostsController(Website.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        // GET: Post/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var post = await _context.Post
                .Include(p => p.Author)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PostId == id);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(post);
        }
    }
}
```

**Post.cs**

```
namespace Website.Models
{
    public class Post   // dependent on Author
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; } // primary key
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }   // author foreign key
        public Author Author { get; set; }  // author navigation property

        public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**In Startup.cs, routing info (never changed this, just default):**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action parameter named `id`. When you use the point with named parameters like this `https://localhost:xxxxx/Posts/Details?PostId=4` MVC tries to serialize the `PostId` to the parameter with the same name. You can rename your parameter or use prefix.

```
Task<IActionResult> Details([Bind(Prefix="PostId")] int? id)
```